# "]" not working

Tags: errors, arrays

I tried to compile something like the following  but it is not compiling:

```
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
    [u,v]=0&,&\text{if bla}\\
    [u,v]=0&,&1
\end{array}
$$
```

I also tried

```
\begin{eqnarray}
    [u,v]=0&,&\text{if bla}\\
    [u,v]=0&,&1
\end{eqnarray}
```

I'm using `pdflatex` (Windows prompt), Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (MiKTeX 2.8), and the compiler shows

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
(to be read again)
           u
1.45                    [u,v]
                     =0 &,&1
?
```

Sincerely, this makes no sense for me and if I delete the "]" in the second line, or if I don't use the second line in the `eqnarray` (or `array`), it compiles normally.

Comment: use `{}[` as otherwise the `[` is taken as the optional argument to `\\ `  also don't use `$$` in latex (this is a duplicate, I'll add a link in a bit)

Comment: Possible duplicates: [“[” Square bracket Curiosities in an `array` environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114422/5764); [Error with table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34466/5764); [“[” as first character in table row](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95236/5764)