# Linebreak followed by bracket

Tags: line-breaking

I tried to find a topic here on this (possible problem) but I didn't.

I reported it at [TeXstudio SF](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907839/thread/6f9a8fae/) but Tim Hoffmann pointed me that it is not a problem of editor. After tested with `nano` and `pdflatex` I'm posting here.

The minimal code produces errors. OK, we can solve it using `\\{}`.

But is this a problem with TeXlive 2014 or there are some good reasons to have that behavior.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
test\\ [foo]

test\linebreak [foo]

test\newline [foo]
\end{document}
```

> ! Missing number, treated as zero.  
>                      f l.3 test\ [foo]

Comment: There are several of these questions, but with more specific contexts than yours: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95236/as-first-character-in-table-row http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34466/error-with-table http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144694/not-working?lq=1 (not an exhaustive list). Voted, for generality. `:-)`

Comment: @PaulGessler, I know about the problem inside arrays and tables. But since my problem is with a simple line, I decided to ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both `\\`  and `\linebreak` take an optional argument, and so you need to end the expansion with `\relax`, so that the bracket is taken as text, and not as an optional argument.  The optional argument for `\\`, if used, is expected to be a length dimension indicating the additional vertical space to provide.  And so `[foo]` does not qualify, thus generating an error.

For `\linebreak`, the optional argument is a number between 0 and 4. According to Lamport, "a larger value of `[num]` more strongly encourages or discourages the line break."  The default is equivalent to 4.  Thus, `[foo]` likewise breaks the expansion of `\linebreak`.

`\newline`, on the other hand, does not take an optional argument, and so `[foo]` following it works fine.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
test\\\relax [foo]

test\linebreak\relax [foo]

test\newline [foo]
\end{document}
```

[image]

For example, `test\\[12pt][foo]`will add a larger gap after `test` and before `[foo]`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
test\\[12pt][foo]

test\linebreak\relax [foo]

test\newline [foo]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ow, how I didn't realize that! Usually I use `\\[xx]` inside arrays but I did never think it as a possible optional argument for `\\` when using in text mode. Thanks.

Comment: @Sigur  It was the use in arrays that clued me in to the nature of your problem.  `\linebreak` on the other hand, I had to do additional research, but figured it was of a similar nature.

Comment: +1: Just had the problem in `tikz`. `\newline` did not work in `tikz` and I ended up using `\\\relax`.