# tikz: Line Break Before a Square Bracket

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187356/
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[align = left] at (0,6) {Line One\\Line Two\\ [Line Three]}; % <-- Problem
    \node[align = left] at (0,4) {Line One\\Line Two\\ Line Three}; % <-- No Problem
    \node[align = left] at (0,2) {Line One\\Line Two\\\relax [Line Three]}; % <-- No Problem
    \node[align = left] at (0,0) {Line One\\Line Two\newline [Line Three]}; % <-- Problem
\end{tikzpicture}
% \linebreak\relax also does not work.

\end{document}
```

- I randomly found a problem in `tikz` today.
- I want to have a line break within a `node`.
- When the line break `\\` is before a square bracket `[` then I got an error (`! Missing number, treated as zero.`).
- Searching the web brought me to [Linebreak followed by bracket](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187356/).
- `\\\relax` *works* but `\newline` does *not* work (`\linebreak\relax` also does *not* work).
- **Question:** Is there a "best practice" to address this problem in a `tikz node`?

PS: I also hope that this question helps others with the same problem to find this post.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `tikz` but also happens outside. `\\ ` has an optional argument, a distance, e.g. `\\[1em]`. If you fill it with something different than a distance, this gives an error. You can use `\\ \mbox{}[]` or similar to avoid the problem.

Comment: @user238301 Thanks for the suggestion (`\mbox`) and the explanation that is has nothing to do with `tikz` in particular.

Comment: Another option is to use a brace group: e.g. `Two\\ {[Line Three]};` instead of `Two\\ [Line Three];`. This prevents the `\\\` treating the square bracket as the start of an optional parameter.

Comment: @peter_gill Ah, thanks. This is also a good solution. Feel free to add an answer.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: I see comments here!

Comment: @mahmood You are right, this question could be closed because it is answered in the comments. I wanted to give the helpful user a chance to provide a proper answer

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.