# Square brackets throw an error while parentheses don't

Tags: errors, line-breaking, conditionals, brackets

Why does the following work

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \Large\textbf{
            \shortstack{
                Assignment 1
                \ifprintanswers\\ (Answer)\fi
            }           
        }
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

while this (after replacing the parenthesis with square brackets in the second printed line) doesn't?

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \Large\textbf{
            \shortstack{
                Assignment 1
                \ifprintanswers\\ [Answer]\fi
            }           
        }
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\\[3pt]` adds 3pt after the linebreak and `\\[answer]` isn't a length, use `\\{} [answer]` (or anything else to hide the `[` from the `\\ `)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187356/ (that has a detailed answer already)